# Over what period is the "Maximum Value of All Deposit Accounts" on Form 8938 to be taken?

Tags: united-states, foreign-income

I'm looking to fill out Part I of [Form 8938](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8938.pdf) for 2016, "Statement of Specified Foreign Financial Assets". On line 2 there is a

> Maximum Value of All Deposit Accounts

Should I fill in the maximum value that the account reached in 2016? Or should the maximum be taken over all time (including now, in 2017)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not filled out the form, but I can quote some IRS instructions.

[Form 8938 Instructions, starting with "Reporting Period"](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8938/ch01.html#d0e1205) (most emphasis in the original, my emphasis in ***bold italic***):

> ### Reporting Period
>
> Unless an exception applies, the ***reporting period for Form 8938 is your tax year.***
>
> **Exception for partial tax years of specified individuals.**   If you are a specified individual for less than the entire tax year, the reporting period is the part of the year that you are a specified individual.
>
> **Example 1.**
>
> John is a calendar year taxpayer. The Form 8938 reporting period begins on January 1 and ends on December 31.
>
> **Example 2.**
>
> Agnes was a single, calendar year taxpayer who died on March 6. The Form 8938 reporting period begins on January 1 and ends on March 6.
>
> **Example 3.**
>
> George, a calendar year taxpayer, is not a U.S. citizen or married. George arrived in the United States on February 1 and satisfied the substantial presence test for the tax year. The Form 8938 reporting period begins on George's U.S. residency starting date, February 1, and ends on December 31.
>
> ### Reporting Maximum Value
>
> You must report the ***maximum value during the tax year*** of each specified foreign financial asset reported on Form 8938. In most cases, the value of a specified foreign financial asset is its fair market value. An appraisal by a third party is not necessary to estimate the maximum fair market value during the year. See *Valuing financial accounts*, and *Valuing other specified foreign financial assets*, later.

That all sounds to me like it should just be the maximum value during the tax year that you're filing for. In general, tax forms only care about your income, deductions, and so forth for the period that you're filing for. You'll deal with balances for the current year when you file the form for it next year.